# Nodejs can't read folder in docker image "no such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, docker

I have created a docker image with the following structure:

```
~ ᐅ kubectl exec -it app-927397ae-fcw6w -- ls -la
total 348
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     26 Oct 15 14:24 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root     17 Oct 15 14:27 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   2859 Oct 15 14:24 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    120 Oct 15 14:24 lib
drwxr-xr-x 509 root root  16384 Oct 15 14:25 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 302681 Oct 15 14:24 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    791 Oct 15 14:24 package.json
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root     38 Oct 15 14:24 postman
```

Inside the lib, I have a file that is trying to read `postman` folder:

```
    files = (files) => {
        fs.readdirSync("../postman").forEach(file => {
            const absPath = path.join("../postman", file);
            if (fs.statSync(absPath).isDirectory()) return this.files(absPath, files);
            else return files.push(absPath);
        });
        
        return files
    }
```

But it's throwing an exception:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '../postman'
    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:955:3)
    at Processor.files (/src/lib/Processor.js:54:12)
    at Processor.run (/src/lib/Processor.js:15:28)
    at new Processor (/src/lib/Processor.js:11:14)
    at Job.job (/src/lib/index.js:11:5)
    at Job.invoke (/src/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:173:10)
    at /src/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:552:11
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/src/node_modules/node-schedule/lib/schedule.js:510:7)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '../postman'
}
```

Is there any secret to make it work inside docker image?

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(process.cwd())` to that file?

Comment: what is the entrypoint of your docker image?

Comment: Its not a docker issue. Its a readdirSync issue. See https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/1326

Comment: the entrypoint of the docker image define the `process.cwd()`, so the fix would be run `path.join(__dirname, '../postman')` or fix the image working directory (that should not be the project directory)